# ir_attachment issue in odoo pod while deploying on IBM cloud

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, cloud, odoo

```
openg2p-erp12-odoo Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                      │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo   File "/opt/bitnami/odoo/lib/odoo-12.0.post20210815-py3.8.egg/odoo/api.py", line 1049, in get                                          │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo     value = self._data[key][field][record._ids[0]]                                                                                      │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo KeyError: 673                                                                                                                           │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                     │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                      │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo   File "/opt/bitnami/odoo/lib/odoo-12.0.post20210815-py3.8.egg/odoo/fields.py", line 1064, in __get__                                   │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo     value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)                                                                                          │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo   File "/opt/bitnami/odoo/lib/odoo-12.0.post20210815-py3.8.egg/odoo/api.py", line 1051, in get                                          │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo     raise CacheMiss(record, field)                                                                                                      │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('ir.attachment(673,).datas', None)                                                                          │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                     │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                      │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo   File "/opt/bitnami/odoo/lib/odoo-12.0.post20210815-py3.8.egg/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 113, in _file_read       │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo     r = base64.b64encode(open(full_path,'rb').read())                                                                                   │
│ openg2p-erp12-odoo FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/bitnami/odoo/data/filestore/openg2p/ba/ba534fd56e5dde52f5a9fe9a8c7451c4cb │
│ 2ba3b3'
```

I'm facing attachment issue while deploying odoo 12 on the IBM cloud. I'm using bitnami helm charts for the deployment of odoo pod on the IBM cloud. I cannot delete tables as "ir_attachment" has media files and has foreign key in another table.

Because of this odoo UI is not showing up and nothing in network logs.

Thanks for the help:)

Comment: Have you checked the access rights on the path? Especially on `/opt/bitnami/odoo/data/filestore` where Odoo will create a folder for every database you create on it.

Comment: @CZoellner how to change access rights?